# website in remote server different localhost like zooming

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

my page is scale like making zoom in remote server and try to change everything in page.
screenshot

localhost:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSH4P.png

page url
http://bit.ly/1JETs2X

Comment: Push Ctrl-0 (that's control + the number zero) to reset the zoom on both tabs, check again. Just a thought :)

Comment: I already rest zoom check to images http://i.imgur.com/5X2TmqU.png and http://i.imgur.com/Qktwld2.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine in my Google Chrome. Maybe, @chris-baker is right, you need to reset the zoom of a window.

Comment: I already rest zoom check to images http://i.imgur.com/5X2TmqU.png and http://i.imgur.com/Qktwld2.png

Comment: @user1657698 I see that your header response doesn't say anything about charset (`Content-Type:text/html`). So I think it might cause this problem. And the web-page looks like on the second screenshot to me too. Try to set `charset=utf-8`.

Comment: @user1657698 I meant, set charset for the server side.

Comment: how do you set charset for the server side?